# I want to collect data from websites and store them in a database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a personal web project with PHP. I want to collect some type of information from website and store them in a table of my database. This information is related to products and services in sale on these website. These items of information are presented differently on the websites I want to use. Can somebody give me clues about how to perform it?
Thanks.

Comment: First clue about how to perform it..... start writing some code

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service**

Comment: So hit the library and read up on HTML/PHP?MYSQL/JAVASCRIPT/CSS and that should get you started

Comment: Google "webscraping + <your scripting language>", in your case php. I'll advise you on using beautiful soup library of python or cheerio of nodejs

Comment: If you are using PHP, look at DOMDocument. You can use this to load an HTML document and to parse it by running an XPath expression. I really like the Goutte library, but bear in mind the docs are not so great for this, so you'd need to use some detective skills to track down the necessary examples.

Comment: thank you verymuch to @halfer your advice is usefull for me

Comment: thank you @AmreshVenugopal your advce helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, try these:

- https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Other packages or extensions can be found by searching for "PHP web scraping".